# Implement VIM support

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor

Is there a possibility to enable VIM support when writing questions and answers? This will allow basic commands to be available in the question/answer textarea on demand. In my opinion, it's the most widely used editor by IT experts.

Lets say all commands from this basic [VIM tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/) without points: 5, 6, 7, 8, 10.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly you expect the editor to have that it does not have now?

Comment: You can do this with a browser plugin - see [Vim interface on web browser input fields?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36257/vim-interface-on-web-browser-input-fields) and [Is there a Firefox add-on to use vim to edit textboxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652/is-there-a-firefox-add-on-to-use-vim-to-edit-textboxes). No need for SE to implement it, and you can use it everywhere on the Internet (not only SE).

Comment: I know there are plugins. But I'm not sure every hotkey from my question is available and doesn't overwrite hotkeys of a browser, furthermore when VIM will be available here, then maybe more people will try to use it and I think it's worth it.

Comment: In the [2015 Stack Overflow developer survey](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-editor), only 15% said vim is their preferred text editor.

Comment: @ff524 Well survey you proposed is not appropriate here, why? Because we cannot implement here Sublime, and about notepad++, it's so simple as our textarea widget now. So vim is next, that's why I'm writing about.

Comment: seems it would be more simpler to use VIM itself and copy and paste the content over to the browser

Comment: I'm doing that every time, but it's overkill.

Comment: Why not emacs bindings? Or Visual Studio bindings? How about options for all of them?

Comment: @Oded I can implement vim extension if you will do the same with emacs :)

Comment: You are missing the point, I think.

Comment: @Oded No, I'm not. I just want to expand possibilities on Stack. That's all.

Comment: I would like to know the reason of downvote this question. I've made that question, because it wasn't exist on Meta Stack and I was curious why we haven't other popular editors implementation. Furthermore I could say: if we have HTML and CSS snippets, then why not user interactive python shell? or C shell or ...

Answer (score 6):

We will not be adding bindings to $favorite-editor - for the reasons others have mentioned, as well as that if we start, there will never be a stop to it (emacs? eclipse? Visual Studio? Some other IDE?).

We believe in good defaults, which is what we have - we don't want to add more and more features and settings that people have to think about and that make the code more complicated for little general benefit.

The solution for you would be in user scripts - take a look at [StackApps](http://stackapps.com).

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think we want this. Vim is only spoken by a group of IT experts, not even all, and IT experts just make up a part of the SE network, not entirely. Adding support will only satisfy them, while it may bother others.

Also, I wonder what the real use is when editing a post. I don't see much need for it myself. If you still think it does, use a browser plugin that converts every text box to allow Vim commands, like those in the posts [ff524](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/254250/ff524) mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36257/126677) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75652/993547).

Comment: As you know writing in vim is faster than in simple textarea widget as it is here without any support. Of course I agree that not all would use it, but maybe will try. We can even make testing AB.

Comment: I wonder how many posts we will get here "my edit box is acting strangely" when they accidentally enabled Vim mode... If you know what you are doing, use a plugin. There is little benefit for SE and the network here.

Comment: We cannot think in this way IMO. "I cannot implement anything, because have to fight with bugs". By default VIM on demand will be disabled and if somebody will decide to use, then will know what to do with and because it's about experts answers, then the same experts will suggest a solution for any bug.

Comment: I am not talking about bugs. SE has a minimal feature set to keep this working for everyone. No fancy stuff, just Q/A. This will distract from just that.

Comment: Of course everyone has its own opinion. I think it's better to help somebody than doing nothing in that case. Maybe more people will try to learn writing in VIM and see that its more efficient, faster and that group of people will raise.